# How do I style an img with CSS3

Tags: image, webkit, icons, css

is it possible to change the background-color of e.g. the first icon of [this site](http://www.kombine.net/wp-content/uploads/kombine-iphone-icons.png) with CSS3, or WebKit’s CSS extensions?

I'm new to this and would appreciate some help. A link or an example would be great.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean by styling the icon? Do you want to change its colour? Its size?

Comment: You can also try -webkit masks (very sparse documentation though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
img {
  background-color: #FF00FF;
}
```

Comment: That won’t actually work though. You’ll get a white background, then the image (which has a black background) on top of it, completely hiding the white background. That declaration won’t have any effect on the image itself.

Comment: it will if if the image has transparency set less than 100%

Comment: sure, it’s just the example image he linked do didn’t.

Answer (score 2):

Although you can style an Image, but changing color of Icon is not possible in CSS3 as it requires Blending modes.

You can achieve this with HTML5 Canvas

```
// Color

var over  = someCanvas.getContext('2d');

// Icon
var under = anotherCanvas.getContext('2d');

over.blendOnto( under, 'screen', {destX:30,destY:15} );
```

use https://github.com/Phrogz/context-blender for achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

If the icon image had a transparent background, then you could set the CSS background colour behind the image like this:

```
background: #c00 url(kombine-iphone-icons.png); /* Puts a red background behind the icon image */
```

Unfortunately, there’s nothing in CSS 3 (or any of WebKit’s CSS extensions) that lets you change the colour of images.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can style an image with css3. But something tells me that you question is actually more specific that it looks like..